# SHIPTOPHONENUM field in the Paypal NVP API not showing up anywhere?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-nvp

My question pertains to the Paypal NVP API.

Has anyone had any issues getting the SHIPTOPHONENUM field (using DoDirectPayment or the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile method) showing up in the Paypal system? For example when viewing activity history:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxtR0_NS7qBZSW5VZ2RUSHFVenM/edit?usp=sharing

There is a "Contact Phone Number" field which never seems to be populated? Also we see the recurring profile a phone field under Billing but none under shipping:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxtR0_NS7qBZdlBuYnIzN0dZQVE/edit?usp=sharing

I'm confused where this is actually used within the paypal system? Can anyone shed any light on where the SHIPTOPHONENUM will actually show up in the Paypal system or why we might not be seeing it anywhere?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

For the Phone field in your recurring profile you need to include PHONENUM in your CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.  PHONENUM is treated as the billing phone number.

Comment: Strange this field does not seem to be listed in the API (unless we are looking at the wrong one)? Is this undocumented? I am referring to the following reference: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/ Thanks for your response.